# Is clustered indexes implemented in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, clustered-index

Why is this code not working? Is it because clustered indexes is not implemented in MySQL?

```
CREATE INDEX niels1 ON `table` CLUSTER (attr1,attr2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know only the InnoDB engine offers clustered indices.
Also, there's no dedicated "CLUSTER" keyword; all PRIMARY KEY indices are CLUSTERed.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: thanks. I know that it clusters on the primary key, but I was wondering if one could define other attributes to create a cluster on.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not a valid syntax for MySQL. See Alex's answer. InnoDB clusters the primary key, other engines do their own thing.

Comment: But to be honest, it was the "table" keyword which is bogus, not the word "CLUSTER", which would be the table's name.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that now. I just inseted table instead of a table name, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

None of the MySQL's storage engines let you choose which index to cluster on as of this day. 01/2013.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like your trying to create a clustered index on table called "CLUSTER".  Maybe you need to do something like:

```
CREATE INDEX niels1 ON CLUSTER (attr1,attr2) USING BTREE;
```